# One domain name - two servers?

Tags: domains, dns, server

I am launching a website now and my boss has bought a hosting service in one webservice company, but they don't support what I need, then we bought another one where we get the support that we need. Now my question is:

If I go to `www.test.com` (e.g.), the website from the first webserver appears. But I also use this domain name in the last new server also. I want that if I go to the url, the website should appear which I run on the second server, not the one which is on the first server.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wanting to just use the new server from now on, and stop using old one? If so, you need to update your DNS records at your domain name registrar.

You'll point them at the new server's nameserver (which you can get from your new host, they'll probably be something like ns1.newhost.com and ns2.newhost.com).

Comment: yeah i am going to stop the old one. where is my domain name registrar?

Comment: Where did you register the domain name originally? Someplace like Register.com, Godaddy, or Network Solutions? If you're not sure, enter the domain name here: http://www.networksolutions.com/whois/index.jsp

Comment: oh okay, but can i also delete the account in the old server, does this solve the problem? the first domain was done in web.de, you know that?

Comment: It won't help to delete anything on the old server. The domain registrar is what tells people how to find your site. If it's still pointing at the old host, people will end up there, no matter what you do on that old host. I haven't heard of web.de.

Comment: oh okay, so domain registrar and domain server are different things? i didnot know that. so in registrar there is normally an accound where you login and set the settings?, if yes, then i need to ask my boss for login data so that i can login and change the dns, right?

Comment: Correct. The registrar will typically be where your domain name system (DNS) servers are specified. You will need to log in there, and modify them to whatever your new host wants.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to tackle this is going to your domain cPanel, change the name servers of your domain to your new hosting provider and wait for it to propergate. It might take some good time like 72 hours to complete where by in that time, your domain will be accesses on two servers not until you its fully propergated. Its time mattering otherwise everything will be okay.

Comment: He never mentioned he used cPanel.